# Displaying one List at a time on Clicking button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

[image]I have a web page where i am displaying list of records using React JS table and each row has a button that shows user a list of action item.If the user clicks on a button in a row and clicks on another button in another row the previous list should hide but both the list are displaying.How to solve this?

```
const dataset = [
{"id" : 1, "buttons" : (<ActionItemList />)},
{"id" : 2, "buttons" : (<ActionItemList />)}
]

<ReactTable data={dataset}  />

const ActionItemList = () => {
   return (
       <div>
          <button>...</button>
        </div>
        <div>
           <ul>
              <li>action-item1</li>
              <li>action-item2</li>
              <li>action-item3</li>
           </ul>
        />
        </div>
      </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Save a reference to the active row, or detect it using a css class ( if you use css to do the show/hide ) so that you can check if any element is visible when clicking a different row. If a previous row is still open, hide it again.

Comment: How do you manage the button (triple dot button) click and open the action items?

Comment: Welcome to world of bad use `e.stopPropagation`?

Comment: validate your view with button id.

Comment: 2 questions, does ActionItemList receive item.id in props and can you use react hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use hooks you can have your menu set the openId with a method passed by a wrapper. Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
import React, { useState, memo, useMemo } from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
//make ActionItemList a pure component using React.memo
const ActionItemList = memo(
  ({ isOpen, setOpenId, id }) =>
    console.log('in render', id) || (
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          isOpen ? setOpenId() : setOpenId(id)
        }
      >
        {isOpen ? 'Close' : 'Open'} Menu
      </button>
    )
);
const dataset = [
  { id: 1 },
  { id: 2 },
  { id: 3 },
  { id: 4 },
];
const columns = [
  { id: 1, accessor: 'id' },
  {
    id: 2,
    //if accessor is a function table will render what function returns
    //  passing in the data where we added isOpen and setOpenId
    accessor: ({ Menu, ...props }) => (
      //passing in the needed props to pure component Menu
      <Menu {...props} />
    ),
  },
];
//wrap this on your react table, adding isOpen and setOpenId
export default () => {
  //set state for open id
  const [openId, setOpenId] = useState();
  //memoize creating the data prop based on openId changing
  const dataWithProps = useMemo(
    () =>
      dataset.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        isOpen: item.id === openId,
        setOpenId,
        Menu: ActionItemList,
      })),
    [openId]
  );
  //return the react table with the extra props in data
  return (
    <ReactTable data={dataWithProps} columns={columns} />
  );
};
```